# Common practices for transparently proxying based on hostname?

Tags: networking, dns, proxy

Here's the scenario:

- Client A issues a DNS query for abc.com and receives IP3.
- Client B later issues a DNS query for r123.com and receives IP3. (let's assume this is possible).
- abc.com is hosted on server1 (IP1). r123.com on server2 (IP2).
- Client A wants to establish a TLS connection to server1. Client B to server2.
- How can this be done transparently? That is, even though Client A and B both connect to IP3, they perceive that the connection has been automatically established with their intended destinations respectively.
- An example implementation that I am not sure would work is: IP3 is a reverse proxy which the clients establish a TCP connection with, later in the clientHello the SNI is retrieved, and the proxy somehow reestablishes a TCP connection between the clients and the actual servers first before proceeding with the TLS handshake?

Edit: in other words, the client should TLS-handshake with the target server, but the trick here is that the DNS query only returns the IP of another server (could be a proxy. Represented by IP3). Multiple domains get this IP3. How can the server at IP3 identify the exact intended server that is requested, while ensuring the TLS-handshake (which contains a TCP handshake too) occurs between the client and the intended server?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: So you want your clients to TLS-handshake with the target servers instead of the proxy server?

Comment: Unclear: How can a computer have two IP addresses? How is the TLS connection done, by IP or DNS? This post seems like an attempt to force a doubtful solution, rather than to explain the real underlying problem.

Comment: Many reverse proxies are already capable of doing this as long as SNI is not [encrypted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication#Encrypted_Client_Hello). The client shake hands with the intended server, though. The proxy only forwards the TCP session along. The rest is just DNS.

Comment: I have edited the question to address the concerns. Also, @harrymc the computer would not have 2 IP addresses

Comment: Still wrong : A TLS connection uses credentials and cannot be done using a wrong IP. I really don't understand your scenario.

Comment: @LeStarfish As I  said, the server at IP3 just have to look at the SNI, which is usually unencrypted. I wrote a [tutorial](https://ventonolitoral.pontofixo.net.br/roteamento-transparente) on how to transparently route TLS traffic using DNS and a reverse proxy. It's not in English, though.

Comment: @harrymc Yes, the TLS handshake happens with the legitimate IP, but TLS certificates authenticate domain names, not IPs. So DNS can answer with a proxy without raising any alarms, provided the TCP/IP packets end up at the right place.